# Build a Django elegant filter with dynamic number of fields

Tags: python, django, filter, django-queryset

I have a Django model which I'm doing a view for it, which filters results.

models.py:

```
Ingredient(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, null=False)
```

Now the point is that the search form (which has every field except `account` of course), none of its fields are required, you can filter either by just a single field or two or the three of them.

The problem is that I can't do:

```
Ingredient.objects.filter(account=account, brand=brand, name=name, cost=cost)
```

...because brand, name, and cost could be sent empty/null

How can I resolve this without making a filter line code for each filtering possibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make a utility function that filters out the `None`s. For example:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def filter_without_none(**kwargs):
    return Q(**{k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None and v != ''})
```

Now we can filter with:

```
Ingredient.objects.filter(
    filter_without_none(account=account, brand=brand, name=name, cost=cost)
)
```

If one (or multiple) of the values like `account`, `brand` and/or `name` are `None`, these will *not* be taken into account for filtering.

Comment: Wow that's an elegant Python code. Thanks! But I'm getting the following error: `ValueError at /Ingredient/filter_by` , `Field 'id' expected a number but got ''.` , 
`The above exception (invalid literal for int() with base 10: '') was the direct cause of the following exception:`. I don't get why it is trying to filter also the field id (which it's not declared in my model but of course it does is in the db table).

Comment: @GonzaloDambra: ah, but that is not `None`, that is the empty string. Can you edit your question with the *traceback* of the error.

Comment: It worked! I just added `and v is not ''` to the `filter_without_none` method. You're right, thats an empty string, not None! Thank you.

Comment: @GonzaloDambra: small remark: I would use `!= ''`. Normally empty strings are indeed "cached". But better be safe than sorry :).